# Proof of inequality $P(X>x)\geq(E(X)-x)^2/E(X^2)$ for every $x$ in $[0,E(X)]$

Tags: probability, expectation

> Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable such that $E(X^2)<\infty$. Show that, for all $0\leq x<EX$, $$P(X>x)\geq\frac{(E(X)-x)^2}{E(X^2)}.$$

I tried to write $E(X)=\int XdP$ and use Cauchy Schwartz, but didn't get very far. Then I tried to take the derivative with respect to $x$ on both side. But that doesn't go well either. Any hints/ideas?

Comment: I think you must require $x \ge 0$.

Comment: I think this is never correct, because it implies that $P(X>E(X)+\sqrt{E(X^2)})=1)$, and then this implies $E(X^2)=0$. !!

Comment: Just a guess: the correct inequality is $P(X>x)\ge \big(E(X-x)_+\big)^2/E(X^2)$, where $x_+ = \max(x,0)$ is the positive part.

Comment: @zhoraster my bad i forgot to say that $0\leq x<EX$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $E(X-x) \le E[(X-x)\cdot\mathbf{1}_{X>x}]$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz to bound the RHS. Expand $E(X-x)^2=E(X^2)  - 2x E(X) +x^2$ to see that it does not exceed $E(X^2)$. QED.